# Tile-like windows on Swing

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, scala

I have zero experience writing applications with Swing, but I have one application with which to start experimenting.

For this application, I want my window to have a variable number of small "tile"-like structures, which can be moved/closed/minimized just like windows by the user inside my main frame, and which will display, each a small table.

I'd like to know what kind of structures should I use to accomplish this. Bonus points for any answers oriented towards Scala Swing.

Comment: CardLayout in swing is something quite different. I'm re-phrsasing your question to use the word "tile" instead

Comment: What is a CardLayout in Swing?

Comment: A CardLayout is for something like a wizard, where you want to have one panel and flip back and forth through the contents (like a stack of index cards).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want something like what's implemented as JDesktopPane/JInternalFrame. This is what's commonly known as MDI. Check out [Sun's "How to Use Internal Frames"](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html) page.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a docking framework is what you are looking for. You could have a look at [InfoNode Docking Windows](http://www.infonode.net/index.html?idw).